# How to remove coordinate specific entries from a matrix?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm having trouble to implement this (seemingly) simple task in Octave/Matlab.

I want to remove specific entries of a set of 2dimensional data. I have sample data (points of x and y coordinates) which contain specific areas that should not be further processed. I want to delete these areas from my sample data.

Here is an example for further understanding what I want to achieve. I would like to have:

B = A **except the data in the red rectangle**

Code Sample:

```
x = 0:pi/64:4*pi;
y = sin(x);

A = [x; y];

% Boundaries of the data that should be deleted
x1 = 4;
x2 = 6;
y1 = -1;
y2 = -0.5;

figure;
hold on;
plot(A(1,:),A(2,:),'bo');
plot([x1 x2 x2 x1 x1],[y1 y1 y2 y2 y1],'r-');
```

I know how to select the data within the red rectangle, which can be done with this command:

```
indices = find(A(1,:)>x1 & A(1,:)<x2 & A(2,:)>y1 & A(2,:)<y2);
B(1,:) = A(1,indices);
B(2,:) = A(2,indices);
plot(B(1,:),B(2,:),'g-x');
```

But I need the opposite: Select the data outside the red rectangle.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not selecting outside with `<x1` instead of inside with `>x1`?

Comment: I tried that but in my sample data there could be points between x1 and x2 that have y > y2, which would be valid data. If I just turned around the "<" and ">" I would discard these valid points, so unfortunately this is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert all of the operators in your statement defining indices (i.e. > becomes < and vice-versa, AND[ & ] becomes OR[ | ]).

```
indices2 = find(A(1,:)<x1 | A(1,:)>x2 | A(2,:)<y1 | A(2,:)>y2);
B=A(:,indices2);
plot(B(1,:),B(2,:),'g-x');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I forgot that logical operations also have to be inverted (although I'm sure that I learned this in one of my courses at the university).

Answer (score 0):

### Use logical arrays to select data

A very handy way of managing selections is the use of logical arrays. This is faster than using indices and allows the easy inversion of a selection as well as the combination of multiple selections. Here comes the modified selection function:
`sel = A(1,:)>x1 & A(1,:)<x2 & A(2,:)>y1 & A(2,:)<y2`
The result is a logical array that is a very memory efficient and fast representation of your information.

See [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtWYW.png) for graphical representation of output.

#### Code Example

```matlab
x = 0:pi/64:4*pi;
y = sin(x);
% Combine data: This is actually not necessary
% and makes the method more complicated. If you can stay with x and y
% arrays formulation becomes shorter
A = [x; y];
    
% Boundaries of the data that should be deleted
x1 = 4;
x2 = 6;
y1 = -1;
y2 = -0.5;

% Select interesting data
sel = A(1,:)>x1 & A(1,:)<x2 & A(2,:)>y1 & A(2,:)<y2;
% easily invert selection with the rest of data
invsel = ~sel;

% Get selected data to a new array
B1 = A(:,sel);
B2 = A(:,invsel);

% Display your data
figure;
hold on;
plot(B1(1,:),B1(2,:),'bo');
plot(B2(1,:),B2(2,:),'rx');

% Plot selection box in green
plot([x1 x2 x2 x1 x1],[y1 y1 y2 y2 y1],'g-');
```

#### Graphical Result

[image: Graphical result of above sample script on selecting data]

[octave](/questions/tagged/octave)
[matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab)